# Insertar en mysql date sin enviar timestamp java

Tags: java, mysql

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy intentado hacer un registro de personas en java hacia mysql.
Donde requiero los datos de Nombre, Apellido, Email, Telefono.
Pero en la db almacena Id, Nombre, Apellido, Email, Telefono, Alta(fecha automática cuando se creo), y Modificación(Para la fecha en cuando se modifico la persona)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que preciso es que al crear la persona solo me grabe la fecha en la columna **Alta**, y no me cargue nada en la columna de **Modificación**.
Estoy usando el siguiente código para enviarlo desde java:

```
ejecuto.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO persona VALUES(NULL,'" + nombre.getText() + "','" + apellido.getText() + "','" + email.getText() + "','" + telefono.getText() + "','"+fecha.getText()+"','"+fecha.getText()+"')");
```

El tema es que es la unica manera para que no me de error al cargar la persona ingresada.
Lo que preciso es que no envie ultimo fecha.getText() que corresponde a la columna de **Modificacion** Hay alguna forma de enviar un NULL? o de evitar que no grabe nada en esa columna de la base de datos? he intentado enviar null, NULL, '' vacios. etc y nada siempre me da error.

La base de datos la tengo configurada asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar agregando una modificación en la tabla de la db poniendo la opción predeterminada como NULL y tildando que acepte NULL
y en el código que hago el insert to lo dejo de la siguiente manera:

```
,'"+fecha.getText()+"',NULL)");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]